# flickering screen

Tags: 17.10

I have installed the ubuntu 17.10 and 16.0, but when it starts up it sometimes suddenly flicker.I have tried to fix it in many ways like this one

```
1. check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...
    boot to the GRUB menu
    choose Advanced Options
    choose Recovery mode
    choose Root access
    at the # prompt, type sudo fsck -f /
    repeat the fsck command if there were errors
    type reboot
```

Update #1:

```
boot to the GRUB menu
select Ubuntu
hit the e key
use arrow keys to move
find the line that has "quiet splash"
add nomodeset, so "quiet splash nomodeset"
hit F10 to exit and continue boot
see if it flickers
```

but the problem still remain, what happened?? and how should i fix it??